# How to load in very large multipage Tiff files

Tags: images, gimp, imagej

Not sure if this is the right site to post this question in, but hope it fits in well here.

I have some very large (think 50kx50k+ pixel) multipage Tiff images I want to load into a program and convert to single page Tiff files. Under the assumption that I have enough Ram to load the image (I do), what program can I load it in that will handle such a large image without crashing or timing out.

I have tried to load it into ImageJ, but that is limited by the Java array max size, so it does not work. I am trying to load into gimp, but that keeps freezing up on me. I've also tried manipulating in python, but the tiffs are LZW compressed and this creates unexpected results when attempting to isolate the pages using pillow with libtiff and numpy.

Any other possible solutions would be much appreciated.
OS is windows 10 or Red hat linux, I'm working on both.

Comment: Photoshop will open 300,000 px^2

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to it currently.

Comment: Questions seeking product recommendations are off-topic. Instead of "with what program?" ask "how to do this?" ([edit] the question). You should also specify your OS.

Answer (score 0):

You might need double the space, which I calculate to be about 20 GB of RAM
all in all. But it could be more than that.

Whatever program you choose, perhaps Gimp, will seem indeed frozen for
a very long time, but could still work.
Unfortunately, any manipulation of the image with the program
will also take a very long time.

You need a hell of a powerful computer to process such images.
Normally this is done with specially-built rigs and professional
(commercial) software.